# How to Change BackColor of dropdown list item based on difference between list date & current date?

Tags: jquery, css, date, date-difference

I have a dropdown list in (MVC View file & using jQuery); which has some text and a substring with date in the format "yyyy-MM-dd", I am able to extract & compare the date with current date & get the difference, however based on that difference I want to specify the back color.

I am storing the dueDate substring into a variable and fetching the current date to get the difference. So if the due date is less than 1 then the item with that particular date need to have a red background. When I am keeping alert() meassage the control is entring into the if statement when the condition is true how ever the code to set background is not working.

The list item whose due date has passed need to have red background. In the snippet below only 1st item need to have red background.`

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#ddldueDate").each(function () {
                //Extracting DueDate - type string
                var SelectedGroup = $(this).children("option").text();
                var dueDateStr = SelectedGroup.substring(SelectedGroup.lastIndexOf('[') + 1, SelectedGroup.lastIndexOf(']'));
                //Get current date - type string
                var d = new Date();
                var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
                var date = d.getDate();
                var currDateStr = d.getFullYear() + '-' + (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' + (date < 10 ? '0' : '') + date;

                var diff = new Date(Date.parse(dueDateStr) - Date.parse(currDateStr));
                var days = diff / 86400000;
                //alert(days);
                if (days < 1) {
                    $(this).children("option").css({ "background-color": "red" });
                } else {
                    $(this).children("option").css({ "background-color": "white" });
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" style="width:auto">
    <select id='ddldueDate' class='form-control'>
      <option>[2019-07-27] Test 1</option>
      <option>[2021-07-24] Test 2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

`

Comment: Provide a *runnable* [mcve]. Click on `<>` in question editor toolbar and can make it run right here in the page

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/7208786 and any solution will probably have limited availability/support in browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can style a default select option with css. Here's the snippet in which I figured out what was required. Answering my own question just in case if anyone can provide any improvements.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#ddldueDate > option").each(function () {
                //Extracting DueDate - type string
                var SelectedGroup = $(this).text();
                var dueDateStr = SelectedGroup.substring(SelectedGroup.lastIndexOf('[') + 1, SelectedGroup.lastIndexOf(']'));
                //Get current date - type string
                var d = new Date();
                var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
                var date = d.getDate();
                var currDateStr = d.getFullYear() + '-' + (month < 10 ? '0' : '') + month + '-' + (date < 10 ? '0' : '') + date;

                var diff = new Date(Date.parse(dueDateStr) - Date.parse(currDateStr));
                var days = diff / 86400000;
                if (days < 1) {
                    $(this).css({ "background-color": "maroon" });
                    $(this).css({ "color": "white" });
                } else {
                    $(this).css({ "background-color": "white" });
                    $(this).css({ "color": "black" });
                }
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12" style="width:auto">
    <select id='ddldueDate' class='form-control'>
      <option>[2020-07-27] Test 1</option>
      <option>[2021-07-24] Test 2</option>
      <option>[2019-07-27] Test 3</option>
      <option>[2019-07-24] Test 4</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This may be different browser to browser.  Chrome does not support this (and if I recall correctly it's not part of the spec)

Comment: I have tested it in Chrome and its working fine in Edge & IE as well...

Comment: Perhaps I'm misinterpreting your question, but when I hit "Run code snippet" I see a normal, un-styled select menu

Comment: Could be possible!!

Comment: this `$(this).css({ "background-color": "maroon" });
                    $(this).css({ "color": "white" });` can simply be `$(this).css({ "background-color": "maroon" ,"color": "white" });` and `$("#ddldueDate > option")` is better written as `$("#ddldueDate").find("option")` due to the right to left processing in the sizzle engine